# Powershell: Copying data from one Excel workbook to another

Tags: c#, powershell, scripting, powershell-4.0

Hello stackoverflow friends!

I have a `Powershell` script I'm working on where I am trying to do the following:

- Select an Excel `xlsx` file with existing worksheets with headers only
- Select a text file
- Create a temporary CSV file from the text file and add headers to match the Excel file
- Copy the information from the CSV file into a worksheet in the Excel file
- Save/Quit

I've got everything I need working up to using the Range aspects of the Excel objects. When attempting to Copy data from the CSV file instantiated as a COM object, then Activating the xlsx file, I am getting an error stating

> Exception calling "Paste" with "1" argument(s): "Paste method of
>   Worksheet class failed" At line:1 char:1
>
> > - $Script:ExcelWorkSheet.Paste($tempRange)
> > - ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> >
> >   - CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
> >   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : ComMethodTargetInvocation

Below is my code thus far. Any help whatsoever would be gratefully appreciated, as I'm at a loss:

```
BEGIN
{
    Function Set-ScriptVars()
    {
        Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
    }

    Function Select-File($FileType)
    {
        ## Select file via selection dialog

        do {
            if($FileType -eq "xlsx")
            {
                Write-Host "`nPlease select the Excel file to import in the dialog"
            }
            elseif($FileType -eq "txt")
            {
                Write-Host "`nPlease select the Prescan or Postscan text file to import in the dialog"
            }

            Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
            $FileBrowser = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog -Property @{InitialDirectory = [Environment]::GetFolderPath('Desktop')}

            [void]$FileBrowser.ShowDialog()

            Write-Host "`nFile selected: " -NoNewline  
            Write-Host $FileBrowser.FileNames -ForegroundColor Yellow 

            $FileName = $FileBrowser.FileName
            if ($FileName.EndsWith(".$FileType"))
            {
                $selectionValid = $True
            }
            else
            {
                Write-Host "The file selected is not a .$FileType file."
                Write-Host "Restarting file selection loop."
                $selectionValid = $False
            }
        } until ($selectionValid -eq $True)

        if($FileType -eq "txt")
        {
            $Script:TextFile = $FileName
            $Script:TextParentPath = (Get-Item $FileName).Directory.FullName
        }
        elseif($FileType -eq "xlsx")
        {
            $Script:ExcelFile = $FileName
            $Script:ExcelParentPath = (Get-Item $FileName).Directory.FullName
        }
    }

    Function Open-Excel($Sheet)
    {
        $ActiveSheet = $Sheet

        $ExcelPath = $Script:ExcelFile
        $Script:Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
        $Script:Excel.Visible = $True
        $Script:Excel.UserControl = $False
        $Script:Excel.Interactive = $False
        $Script:Excel.DisplayAlerts = $False

        $Script:ExcelWorkBook = $Script:Excel.Workbooks.Open($ExcelPath)
        $Script:ExcelWorkSheet = $Script:Excel.WorkSheets.item($ActiveSheet)
        $Script:ExcelWorkSheet.Activate()
    }

    Function Get-TextContent()
    {
        $Script:TextContent = Get-Content $Script:TextFile 
    }

    Function Copy-TextData()
    {
        # create a random file name

        $randomInt = @(0001..9999) | Get-Random
        $tempCSV = Import-CSV $Script:TextFile -Header "Server","Role","Type","Object","Path" 
        $tempCSV | Export-CSV -Path $ENV:USERPROFILE\Desktop\tempCSV_$randomInt.csv -NoTypeInformation
        $tempCSVPath = "$ENV:USERPROFILE\Desktop\tempCSV_$randomInt.csv"
        $tempCSVName = "tempCSV_$randomInt"

        # create a temporary file to copy from

        $TempExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
        $TempExcel.Visible = $True
        $TempWorkBook = $TempExcel.WorkBooks.Open($tempCSVPath)
        $TempWorkSheet = $TempWorkBook.WorkSheets.Item($tempCSVName)

        $tempRange = $TempWorkSheet.Range("A2:E2").UsedRange
        $tempRange.Copy() | Out-Null

        $Script:ExcelWorkSheet.Activate()
        $Script:ExcelWorkSheet.Range("A2:E2").EntireColumn
        $Script:ExcelWorkSheet.Paste($tempRange)
        $Script:ExcelWorkBook.Save()
        $Script:Excel.Quit()

        [gc]::Collect()
        [gc]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()

        Write-Host "Break"
    }
}

PROCESS
{
    Set-ScriptVars
    Select-File -FileType "xlsx"
    Select-File -FileType "txt"
    if($Script:TextFile -match "Prescan")
    {
        Open-Excel -Sheet "Prescan"
    }
    elseif($Script:TextFile -match "Postscan")
    {
        Open-Excel -Sheet "Postscan"
    }

    Get-TextContent
    Copy-TextData
}

END
{

}
```

In this case, utilizing VB macros is not an option.
If such a task is more easily accomplished by leveraging a .NET assembly or dropping in C# code in a @'  '@ format, I'm all ears!

Answer (score 0):

After spending a great deal of time, I finally came to a workable solution.
For anyone who may come across this through a search engine in the future, I hope the code below helps!

```
BEGIN
{
    Function Set-ScriptVars()
    {
        Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
    }

    Function Select-File($FileType)
    {
        ## Select file via selection dialog

        do {
            if($FileType -eq "xlsx")
            {
                Write-Host "`nPlease select the Excel file to import in the dialog"
            }
            elseif($FileType -eq "txt")
            {
                Write-Host "`nPlease select the Prescan or Postscan text file to import in the dialog"
            }

            Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
            $FileBrowser = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog -Property @{InitialDirectory = [Environment]::GetFolderPath('Desktop')}

            [void]$FileBrowser.ShowDialog()

            Write-Host "`nFile selected: " -NoNewline  
            Write-Host $FileBrowser.FileNames -ForegroundColor Yellow 

            $FileName = $FileBrowser.FileName
            if ($FileName.EndsWith(".$FileType"))
            {
                $selectionValid = $True
            }
            else
            {
                Write-Host "The file selected is not a .$FileType file."
                Write-Host "Restarting file selection loop."
                $selectionValid = $False
            }
        } until ($selectionValid -eq $True)

        if($FileType -eq "txt")
        {
            $Script:TextFile = $FileName
            $Script:TextParentPath = (Get-Item $FileName).Directory.FullName
        }
        elseif($FileType -eq "xlsx")
        {
            $Script:ExcelFile = $FileName
            $Script:ExcelParentPath = (Get-Item $FileName).Directory.FullName
        }
    }

    Function Open-Excel($Sheet)
    {
        $ExcelPath = $Script:ExcelFile
        $Script:Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
        $Script:Excel.Visible = $False
        $Script:Excel.UserControl = $False
        $Script:Excel.Interactive = $True
        $Script:Excel.DisplayAlerts = $False

        $Script:ExcelWorkBook = $Script:Excel.Workbooks.Open($ExcelPath)
        $Script:ExcelWorkSheet = $Script:Excel.WorkSheets.item($Sheet)
        $Script:ExcelWorkSheet.Activate()
    }

    Function Get-TextContent()
    {
        $Script:TextContent = Get-Content $Script:TextFile 
    }

function Release-Ref ($ref) { 
    ([System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject( 
    [System.__ComObject]$ref) -gt 0) | Out-Null
    [System.GC]::Collect() 
    [System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers() 
} 
    Function Copy-TextData()
    {       
        # create a CSV from the scan data

        $Script:TextContent = Get-Content $Script:TextFile

        $data = @()
        $row = New-Object PSObject

        foreach($line in $Script:TextContent)
        {
            if($line -eq "CSV was validated without errors." -or $line -eq "")
            {
                Out-Null
            }
            else
            {
                $i = 0
                $values = $line -split ","
                $result = [PSCustomObject]@{Server=$values[0];`
                                            Role=$values[1];`
                                            Object=$values[2];`
                                            Type=$values[3];`
                                            Path=$values[4]
                                           }

                [Array]$results = $results + $result
            }
        }
        $csvName = "scanData_" + "$(@(000..999) | Get-Random)"
        $results | Export-CSV -Path "$ENV:USERPROFILE\Desktop\$csvName.csv" -NoTypeInformation
        $csvPath = $(Get-Item $ENV:USERPROFILE\Desktop\$csvName.csv).VersionInfo.FileName

        # Remove header generated by hashtable
        # and skip the next two lines

        $tempContent = Get-Content $csvPath
        $replacementContent = $tempContent | Select -Skip 3
        Set-Content $csvPath -Value $replacementContent

        # create temporary workbook and save as xlsx
        $tempXL = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
        $tempXL.Visible = $False
        $tempXL.UserControl = $False
        $tempXL.Interactive = $True
        $tempXL.DisplayAlerts = $False

        $tempWB = $tempXL.WorkBooks.Open("$csvPath")
        $tempWS = $tempWB.WorkSheets

        $convertedName = $csvPath.Replace(".csv",".xlsx")
        $tempWB.SaveAs($convertedName,1)
        $tempWB.Saved = $True

        $tempRange = $tempWB.Worksheets.Item(1).UsedRange
        $tempRange.Copy()

        if($Script:logSelection -eq "Prescan")
        {
            $permRange = $Script:ExcelWorkBook.Worksheets.Item(2)
        }
        else
        {
            $permRange = $Script:ExcelWorkBook.Worksheets.Item(3)
        }

        $subRange = $permRange.Range("A2","E2")
        $permRange.Paste($subRange)
        $permRange.Columns.AutoFit()

        $Script:ExcelWorkBook.Save()
        $Script:ExcelWorkBook.Saved = $True
        $Script:Excel.Quit()

        $tempWB.Save()
        $tempWB.Saved = $True
        $tempXL.Quit()

        Release-Ref($Script:ExcelWorkSheet)
        Release-Ref($tempWS)

        Release-Ref($Script:ExcelWorkBook)
        Release-Ref($tempWB)

        Release-Ref($Script:Excel)
        Release-Ref($tempXL)

        Remove-Item $csvPath -Force
        Get-Item $convertedName | Remove-Item -Force
    }

    Function Prompt-ReRun
    {
        do
        {
            $openChoice = Read-Host "`nRun again? (y/n)"
            $openChoice = $openChoice.ToLower()
        } until($openChoice -eq "y" -or $openChoice -eq "n")

        if($openChoice -ne "y" -and $openChoice -ne "n")
        {
            Write-Host "Invalid entry"
        }
        elseif($openChoice -eq "y")
        {
            Run-Selection
        }
        else
        {
            Out-Null
        }
    }

    Function Run-Selection
    {
        Select-File -FileType "xlsx"
        Select-File -FileType "txt"
        if($Script:TextFile -match "Prescan")
        {
            Open-Excel -Sheet "Prescan"
            $Script:logSelection = "Prescan"
        }
        elseif($Script:TextFile -match "Postscan")
        {
            Open-Excel -Sheet "Postscan"
            $Script:logSelection = "Postscan"
        }

        Get-TextContent
        Copy-TextData
        Prompt-ReRun
    }
}

PROCESS
{
    Set-ScriptVars
    Run-Selection
}

END
{

}
```